# is the 'warm start' option of dlib's dcd trainer only for 1-class classification?

Tags: c++, image-processing, classification, svm, dlib

I am using `dlib` for a program that classifies medical images using SVM. Because the images are large (many features, say 10000 to 100000) and I use a linear kernel, it sounds as though the `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` is a good class to use.

Another reason that I like the `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` class is that it claims to support 'warm starting', so if a single observation is often added to/subtracted from the sample (such as in LOOCV) that is efficient for long vectors.

But the only example of `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` uses one_class classification. The documentation suggests that the `force_last_weight_to_1` option that implements the warm start, is for 1-class classification only.

Is that true, i.e. is this warm-start option not available for binary classification? An in that case, would another implementation be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a limitation.  Did you read the documentation for the class? http://dlib.net/dlib/svm/svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer_abstract.h.html#svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer  Where in dlib's documentation does it say warm-starting is limited to one class classification.  The documentation for the svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer doesn't even mention one class classification near as I can see.

Comment: What is the “dob”?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the documentation it does not really say how to do a warm start? I found the link with the force-to-1 option in the example program, and the comments there made me think that it was for 1-class classifiers...

Comment: "But putting the empirical_kernel_map aside, the most important step in turning a linear SVM into a one-class SVM is the following. We append a -1 value onto the end of each feature vector and then tell the trainer to force the weight for this feature to 1."

Comment: Ok. That’s just talking about how to construct a one class classifier. Read the api documentation to find out about a specific dlib object.

Comment: OK, so warm starting is done by the `optimizer_state` class template and the `train()` function using that, and has nothing to do with forcing weights to 1 or bias. I found the `active_learning.h` example and it makes more sense now!